Anime with a red-haired boy protagonist who can turn into a panda summoned into another realm with a group of friends from his village
Red haired boy with group of 6 or so friends from same village. They all advance and get brought to next realm where each of them gets chosen by a new teacher and sent to different schools/locations.
The boy can turn into a panda when fighting and has mastery of 2 or 3 energies?  Most people have only 1.
He has a yellow chick, spirit soul, that hatched from egg and eats spirit stones/dark energy.
The boy and all his friends are reincarnated but only he remembers their past lives.
He has a tree growing in his soul sea and a cauldron he can make pills in?
He saves a girl in wheelchair who'd been poisoned by her cousin.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?

Just to check, this sounds like some kind of isekai/cultivation anime?

You are looking for Tales of Demons and Gods available in light novel, manhua, and donghua Tales of Demons and Gods (妖神记, Yaoshenji) by Mad Snail (发飙的蜗牛).

Killed by a Sage Emperor and reborn as his 13 year old self, Nie Li was given a second chance at life. A second chance to change
everything, save his loved ones and his beloved city. He shall once
again battle with the Sage Emperor to avenge his death. With the vast
knowledge he accumulated in his previous life, he shall have a new
starting point. Although he started as the weakest, without a doubt,
he will climb the steps towards the strongest.
Cultivating the strongest cultivation technique, wielding the strongest demon spirits, he shall reach the pinnacle of Martial Arts.
Enmities of the past will be settled in this new lifetime.
“Since I’m back, then in this lifetime, I shall become the King of Gods that dominates everything. Let everything else tremble beneath my
feet!”


Can you address some of the points raised in the question (pandas, chicks, trees, soul seas, cauldrons, etc etc)?

@Valorum According to a web search of “tales of demons and gods soul sea”, “Manhua Variant: [soul realm] Name is changed to "Soul Sea." A demon spiritualist can form a soul realm within their "energy center," or dantian.” Also, according to a web search of “tales of demons and gods panda”, “Nie Li's Fanged Panda demon spirit was refined in the Nightmare Demon Pot and has some special mutations that led to it being far more powerful than most”
